# could not download R Studio using ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, gnome, r, gdebi

I want to install R Studio based on [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/rstudio-for-ubuntu/)
but I got stuck at part `sudo gdebi –n rstudio-0.99.896-amd64.deb`
and
it says `gdebi error, file not found: –n`

I m using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: still gdebi error, file not found: ––n sir

Comment: @FachryDzaky Seems you're using [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) `–`. Consider using hyphen `-`. (Observe the lengths)

Comment: If you're on 18.04.3, your issue maybe because you're system is behind on updates.  Ubuntu 18.04.3 implies you've not maintained your system since before 12 February 2020 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/ but installed systems will have upgraded to it before that date, as the date signifies the release of the ISO itself). A fully upgraded system will not report 18.04.5

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt -y install r-base`

later  r-studio with gdebi.

I also installed all r-studio packages from synaptic.

Just type following command in terminal:  `sudo  apt install synaptic`

Then in synaptic write r studio.

Im using  Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

And r  studio works fine.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify. It is impossible to "in synaptic write r studio.". This package does not came from any repository, and usually installed as single deb-package downloaded from official site. Write your answer in more reproducible way.

Comment: @N0rbert https://i.postimg.cc/nrbgRpyN/Zrzut-ekranu-z-2020-09-09-06-23-21.png

Comment: I do not see instruction in your answer, it is a mess.