# cant start R studio on ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, gnome, r, rstudio, gdebi

i used this tutorial to install RStudio https://linuxhint.com/rstudio-for-ubuntu/

but when i started on this phase `sudo gdebi -n rstudio-0.99.896-amd64.deb`

it's says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libgstreamer0.10-0
```

Comment: If you're on 18.04.3, your issue maybe because you're system is behind on updates.  Ubuntu 18.04.3 implies you've not maintained your system since before 12 February 2020 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/ but installed systems will have upgraded to it before that date, as the date signifies the release of the ISO itself). A fully upgraded system will not report 18.04.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [could not download R Studio using ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273507/could-not-download-r-studio-using-ubuntu)

Comment: I'd also check your sources, the package you're after is available for xenial (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libgstreamer0.10) so there are likely more details than you've provided that relate. 18.04.3 implies your system is unmaintained, *xenial* packages that you've possibly polluted your sources..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rstudio-0.99.896-amd64.deb` is completely outdated. You are referring to the 3 years old post.

You should use official RStudio packages source - https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ and download *Ubuntu 18/Debian 10* variant from it using download link or programmatically:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.3.1073-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-1.3.1073-amd64.deb
```

Comment: this is what i want sir, thankyou very much